# How to speed up processing time of AWS Transcribe?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have 6 second audio recording(`ar-01.wav`) in `wav` format. I want to transcribe the audio file to text using amazon services. For that purpose I created a bucket by name `test-voip` and uploaded the audio file to bucket. When I try to convert the speech to text, a 6 second audio is taking 13.12 seconds. Here is my code snippet

```
session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id, 
aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
transcribe = session.client('transcribe', region_name='us-east-1')
job_name = "audio_text_trail9"
job_uri = "https://test-voip.s3.amazonaws.com/ar-01.wav"
transcribe.start_transcription_job(
    TranscriptionJobName=job_name,
    Media={'MediaFileUri': job_uri},
    MediaFormat='wav',
    LanguageCode='en-US',
    MediaSampleRateHertz=16000
    )

while True:
    status = transcribe.get_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName=job_name)
    if status['TranscriptionJob']['TranscriptionJobStatus'] in ['COMPLETED', 'FAILED']:
        break
print("converted to text")
myurl = status['TranscriptionJob']['Transcript']['TranscriptFileUri']
print(myurl)
Text_Data = (requests.get(myurl).json())['results']['transcripts'][0]['transcript']

print(Text_data)
```

Here my code is working fine and the accuracy is awesome even on a noisy audio, but the time consumption is too high. Where did I do the mistake and what is dragging that much huge time to transcribe? Once I get the transcribed `json`, time for extracting the information required is negligible. How to speed up the process for transcribe or is there any other better way to do it?

Comment: Why is the time an issue for you? Is it a problem if an n-second clip takes longer than n-seconds to process?

Comment: Does AWS make any guarantees how fast the file will be processed? They might be spinning up a new instance for you somewhere which takes a few seconds, or your file will have to wait in a queue before it can be processed. That's why the API is *job based* and not a synchronous immediately returning API.

Comment: John, yes I need it to be faster for My application.

Comment: You can try uploading a larger file, and see if the processing time goes up linearly. If so, it's simply doing a lot of processing and it needs that time. If the time doesn't go up significantly (e.g. it takes 20 seconds for a 60 second audio file), that means there's simply a certain overhead in starting a job. Either way, I'd expect it to already work as fast as it can and there's no secret `--doubletime` switch.

Comment: running even my python code on AWS server will make any difference ?

Comment: @deceze: The time is approx double the time. I tried with multiple files with different duration, and the results are the same for every file. Like 1 min audio takes 2 min, 10 sec audio takes 20 sec approx.

Comment: So it probably simply needs that time to do its thing. If it's too slow for your needs, talk to AWS.

Answer (score 2):

For me, AWS Transcribe took 20 minutes to transcribe a 17 minute file. One possible idea is to split the audio file in chunks and then use multiprocessing with 16 cores at EC2, like a g3.4xlarge instance.

Split the audio file in 16 parts with a silence threshold of -20, then convert to .wav:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mp3splt
$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
$ mp3splt -s -p th=-20,nt=16 splitted.mp3
$ ffmpeg -i splitted.mp3 splitted.wav
```

Then, use the multiprocessing with 16 cores transcribing simultaneously, mapping your transcribe function (transcribe.start_transcription_job) for each one of the TranscriptionJobName and job_uri's:

```
import multiprocessing

output=[]
data = range(0,16)

def f(x):
    job_name = "Name"+str(x)
    job_uri = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/splitted"+str(x)+".wav"
    transcribe.start_transcription_job(
    TranscriptionJobName=job_name,
    Media={'MediaFileUri': job_uri},
    MediaFormat='wav',
    LanguageCode='pt-BR',
    OutputBucketName= "bucket",
    MediaSampleRateHertz=8000,
    Settings={"MaxSpeakerLabels": 2,
      "ShowSpeakerLabels": True})
    while True:
        status = transcribe.get_transcription_job(TranscriptionJobName=job_name)
        if status['TranscriptionJob']['TranscriptionJobStatus'] in ['COMPLETED','FAILED']:
            break

def mp_handler():
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(16)
    r=p.map(f, data)
    return r

if __name__ == '__main__':
    output.append(mp_handler())
```

Comment: The project which I trying was stopped due to the time issue. I will give a try and hope I can restart my project if the solution works! I will post the result soon.

Answer (score 2):

I have researched for a trascription speed guarantee with no luck

In [this forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=854301) (requires an aws account) a poster makes a benchmark with the following results:

- A 10 minute clip took about 5 minutes
- 40 minute clips take around 17 minutes
- a 2 hour file took 36 minutes

What seems to be an official Amazon source states that "At this time, transcription speeds are better optimized for audio longer than 30 seconds. You'll start to see a better processing time to audio duration time ratio when the audio file length is about 2 minutes or longer. Having said, this we are working hard to enhance transcription speeds overall"

I hope it helps researchers